# ld: meta method 'UIBarButtonSystemItem:' in category from [...]/libReactNativeNavigation.a conflicts with same method from another category

Tags: ios, react-native, ld, react-native-navigation

While compiling my react-native project, and since I'm using react-native-navigation I have 2 warnings :

```
▸ Linking Companion
⚠️  ld: meta method 'UIBarButtonSystemItem:' in category from /Users/zedtux/Developments/companion/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReactNativeNavigation.a(RCTConvert+UIBarButtonSystemItem.o) conflicts with same method from another category
⚠️  ld: meta method 'UIModalPresentationStyle:' in category from /Users/zedtux/Developments/companion/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReactNativeNavigation.a(RCCManagerModule.o) conflicts with same method from another category
```

How could I fix those 2 issues?